# С чего начать изучать MySQL

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте, сколько раз пытался взяться за учение MySQL, все без успешно.

Подскажите, с чего лучше всего начать? 
P.S. Читал FAQ для новичков, нет подробного обзора - часто путаюсь в коде и попросту не понимаю куда его вставлять.
За ранее благодарю.

Comment: Хорошее начало для практики
[SQL упражнения](http://www.sql-ex.ru) На данном сайте я получил сертификат базовый. На собеседованиях на позицию разработчика SQL задачи щелкал как орешки. Всем рекомендую!

Comment: С реляционной алгебры

Answer (score 3):

Начать имеет смысл с установки MySQL к себе на компьютер. Затем — пробовать и экспериментировать. Интереснее всего сходу начать решать некую реальную задачу, самую простую из существующих. Например, создать таблицу для адресной книги и занести туда все свои контакты, и написать запрос, который выводит телефоны всех девушек : )

Чтобы не возиться с установкой, можно взять готовые "пакеты". Под Windows часто ставят [Denwer](http://www.denwer.ru/). Под Mac OS X — [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html). После этого сможете выполнять и напрямую SQL запросы через веб-интерфейс phpMyAdmin, и выполнять простенькие и не очень php скрипты, обращающиеся к базе данных.

Comment: Лучше не денвер а http://open-server.ru/

Comment: @zhekonya пара слов, почему. Чтобы не выглядеть голословным, и удовлетворить моё любопытство. А то я от винды далёк.

Comment: лень писать...))) почитайте http://theweb20.net/webdev/raznoe/open-server-alternativa-denweru-est и http://nebox.ru/soft/open-server-zamenit-denwer/ к примеру

Comment: Похоже, Вы просто продвигаете этот орen-server, ах вы спамер такой-сякой! ) Ссылки на сайт проекта и перепост оттуда.

Альтернатив Denwer'у много: вот [сравнение AMP стеков под Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WAMPs). И этот флейм закрывайте, не по теме вопроса, и не по правилам Хэшкода.

Answer (score 0):

`MySQL` - это запросы - сначала поставьте то, через что будете посылать запросы. У меня, например, стоит `MysqlYog` = и потом в окне запроса пишите их, лучше если купите за 100 рублей книгу типа кукбук или мускул за 24 часа, потратите несколько дней, натренируетесь, а там видно будет.

Answer (score 0):

Начните с основ SQL.

И.Ф.Астахова, А.П.Толстобров, В.М.Мельников "SQL в примерах и задачах". Я начинал с этого учебного курса. Потом  можно почитать Мартина Грубера - Понимание SQL. Начинайте изучение с простых запросов и таблиц. Потом постепенно сами начнёте понимать, как и что.

Затем уже обращайтесь к документации MySQL, языка программирования. Для решения конкретной задачи этого более чем достаточно. Смотрите вебинары, читайте тематические форумы.

**UPD:** Забыл написать, что не плохо бы знать английский язык. Т.к. язык запросов весьма прост и строится как обычная фраза. Триггеры, циклы, ветвления - это всё придет с опытом и чтением документации, форумов, статей... В общем, *глаза боятся,а руки делают* (ц) Русская народная поговорка.

Answer (score 0):

MySql это система управления базами данных. Управление осуществляется через запросы на языке SQL. Для всех субд SQL одинаков, но каждая СУБД добавляет какие то свои возможности...  С начало ознакомитесь с тем что такое базы данных для чего они нужны... после этого изучайте SQL. А потом можно и работать с СУБД.